# ask the user whether they want to start the quiz again or quit the quiz after answering 5 questions

Tags: python-3.x

All the code is fine except the restart part.the purpose of this part is to ask the user whether they want to do the quiz again or quit the quiz after they answer 5 questions ,however i just cant do it.

```
  import random
**restart == "yes"
while restart == "yes":**------this is the main part of the problem.whenever i run the program it says that restart is not defined and i just get even more confused.please,please help.
 print("1.Addition")
 print("2.Subtraction")
 print("3.Multiplication")
 print("4.Division")
 print("5.exit")
 score = 0 
 choice1=int(input("please select an option by entering the number\n"))
 if choice1 == 1:
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"+",num2)
     answer = num1 + num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score = score + 1
     if q1 != answer:
         print("incorrect")
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"+",num2)
     answer = num1 + num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score =score + 1
     if q1 != answer:
         print("incorrect")
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"+",num2)
     answer = num1 + num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score = score +1
     if q1 != answer:
         print("incorrect")
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"+",num2)
     answer = num1 + num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score = score + 1
     if q1 != answer:
        score = score + 1
        print("incorrect")
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"+",num2)
     answer = num1 + num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score = score + 1
         print(score)
     if q1 != answer:
         print("incorrect")
     print("your score out of 5 is")
     print(score)
 if choice1 == 2:
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"-",num2)
     answer = num1 - num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score = score + 1
     if q1 != answer:
         print("incorrect")
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"-",num2)
     answer = num1 - num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score =score + 1
     if q1 != answer:
         print("incorrect")
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"-",num2)
     answer = num1 - num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score = score + 1
     if q1 != answer:
         print("incorrect")
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"-",num2)
     answer = num1 - num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score = score + 1
     if q1 != answer:
         print("incorrect")
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"-",num2)
     answer = num1 - num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score = score + 1
         print(score)
     if q1 != answer:
         print("incorrect")
     print("your score out of 5 is"/n)
     print(score)
 if choice1 == 3:
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"*",num2)
     answer = num1 + num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score = score + 1
     if q1 != answer:
         print("incorrect")
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"*",num2)
     answer = num1 + num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score =score + 1
     if q1 != answer:
         print("incorrect")
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"*",num2)
     answer = num1 + num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score = score +1
     if q1 != answer:
         print("incorrect")
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"*",num2)
     answer = num1 + num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score = score + 1
     if q1 != answer:
        score = score + 1
        print("incorrect")
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"*",num2)
     answer = num1 + num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score = score + 1
         print(score)
     if q1 != answer:
         print("incorrect")
     print("your score out of 5 is",score)
 if choice1 == 4:
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"/",num2)
     answer = num1 - num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score = score + 1
     if q1 != answer:
         print("incorrect")
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"/",num2)
     answer = num1 - num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score =score + 1
     if q1 != answer:
         print("incorrect")
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"/",num2)
     answer = num1 - num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score = score + 1
     if q1 != answer:
         print("incorrect")
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"/",num2)
     answer = num1 - num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score = score + 1
     if q1 != answer:
         print("incorrect")
     num1 = random.randint(1,5)
     num2 = random.randint(1,5)
     print ("what is",num1,"/",num2)
     answer = num1 - num2
     q1 = int(input(""))
     if q1 == answer:
         print ("good")
         score = score + 1
         print(score)
     if q1 != answer:
         print("incorrect")
     print("your score out of 5 is"/n)
     print(score)
 if choice1 == 5:
     print("bye,bye")
     exit()
```

**restart=input("Do you want to start the quiz again?Yes?No?")
    if restart == "no":
        quit**-----this is one part of the problem as well as the one below.

Comment: Please remove the `blockqoute` paragraphs.

Comment: It would help (the readers and you!) if you trimmed down the code to the minimum to show the error or problematic behaviour. As you indicated, the problem is in lines 2 and 3, the remainder is almost completely irrelevant. Narrowing down the source of a problem in this way is good practice not only in software engineering.

Comment: _"i just cant do it"_ isn't a problem description. Nor is _"this is one part of the problem as well as the one below"_, at least without anything below... See the Help Centre on how to ask good questions. _"Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"_

Answer (score 1):

look at the definition of restart:

```
restart == "yes" # incorrect!
```

this is correct:

```
restart = "yes" #correct
#rest of the code
```

and you should use `\n` instead of `/n` for new lines